# Can't seem to increment a property of an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function LetterCountI(str)
>   take the str parameter being passed and return the first word with the
>   greatest number of repeated letters. For example: "Today, is the
>   greatest day ever!" should return greatest because it has 2 e's (and 2
>   t's) and it comes before ever which also has 2 e's. If there are no
>   words with repeating letters return -1. Words will be separated by
>   spaces.

I'm half way there, but I am stuck at this point:

```
function LetterCountI(str) { 
  str = str.split(' ');
  var letterController = {}, count = 0, brokenString;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    brokenString = str[i].split('');
    for (var j = 0; j < brokenString.length; j++) {
      if (letterController.hasOwnProperty[brokenString[j]]) {
        letterController[brokenString[j]] += 1;
      } else {
        letterController[brokenString[j]] = count;
      }
    }  
  }
  return letterController;       
}
```

I get the following:

```
Object {H: 0, e: 0, l: 0, o: 0, a: 0…}
```

I don't want the solution to the task at large, just how to increment count for the object properties! It's confounding me!

Comment: you're indexing into `hasOwnProperty` with square brackets `[]` rather than calling it with parens `()`

Comment: You'll want to initialise them with `1`, not `0` - or always increment after possibly initialising. And you don't really need that `count` variable.